Is it a good idea to have a fork of a library's public repo in my solution?
My company's project uses an open source library, of which I have made a fork for some customizations. My idea is to clone this fork into my solution and to keep pushing my changes into it, as well as pull changes from the public repo every once in a while and merge carefully, so I can always be up-to-date with the latest features. Is this a good idea or will it cause problems in the long run?

The alternatives are called bundling vs. requiring a library, and there's a lot to be said about both options - you should read up on the question under those terms.

There are two aspects to your question that I want to answer separately
Having a copy of a library in your repository
If you store a copy of a third-party library in a repository that you own, you have the advantage that you know that the version of the library that the rest of your product depends on will be available for as long as you need it. You can be sure of that, because you control when that code gets deleted.
On the other hand, having a copy in a repository of yours also puts a maintenance burden on you, because you have to make sure the copy gets updated in a timely fashion when important updates are made available by the upstream developers. And that involves not only normal bug fixes and new features, but also security updates.
Which aspect is more important depends heavily on the kind of product you have and for how long old versions need to remain actively supported.
Having a fork with local changes
When you add local changes into the mix, the maintenance burden goes up exponentially. Besides the points above about having a local copy, you now also become responsible for re-applying the local changes each time that you pull an update from upstream.
Here I strongly recommend that you negotiate with management that you are allowed to get those local changes incorporated into the official library. Then the burden for maintaining those- changes shifts to the library maintainers.

To know version of library, pin the version in your dependency management tool. Version pinning is not a reason to "vendor" it.

@Basilevs, that doesn't help if you need to retrieve that version after upstream has deleted it. I have a requirement that I must be able to reproduce my release binary exactly for 15 years. Most suppliers don't guarantee the availability of their releases for such a long time, so for a lot of it we store a copy out of necessity.

why does not it help? Maven, NPM and PyPi have protections against deletions from official repositories, don't they?
https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish

@Basilevs, where do those services guarantee that they are still in business 15 years from now, let alone that they haven't cleaned up packages older than N years and downloaded less than M times in the last X time. I couldn't find such a guarantee in the NPM terms and it is expensive to keep such old software lying around on the off-chance that someone needs it.

@Basilevs that npm link defines precise conditions where versions can be removed.

@Caleth, yes. My point is that conditions are defined and well-known and can be relied upon as long as you trust NPM.

@BartvanIngenSchenau if you don't rely on Maven and NPM to be present in 15 years, then sure, you have to vendor either by a copy to source base of by maintaining your own repository. But that's a trivial conclusion, why would we discuss it?

@Basilevs, For our, rather extreme use-case, the conclusion was indeed obvious.For a typical modern app, it is probably far more advantageous to use NPM, Maven PiPy or similar, but that is a consideration that needs to be made at the company and/or project level.

You will definitely spend a lot of time on maintenance, merging upstream changes. You will also lose the most important benfit of OS - free support.
Only do so, if customization contradicts project's policies or their release cycle is unacceptably long. Even then, try to eliminate the copy at the earliest opportunity.
